# Multithread testing

Tags: java, multithreading, testing

I have a task to firstly write a multithread client server application and then to test it with lot of clients (100 clients each sending 1000 messages). So I have working properly console client-server. Client has two threads one for input other for output. And now I start to write test. In my opinion it working schema should be like: execute server thread that should waiting for accept new client, after that I would execute InputThreads (connect it to the server) and in the cycle write in it testing protocols. Am I right?

So I write something like this:

```
public class ServerLoadTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServerLoadTest.class);
    private ExecutorService clientExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    private ExecutorService serverExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, JAXBException, XMLStreamException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, InterruptedException {        
        LOG.trace("Start testing");     
        serverExec.execute(new TestServerThread());     

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
            clientExec.execute(new TestClientThread());
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        LOG.trace("All working fine");
        clientExec.shutdown();
    }

}


class TestClientThread implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestClientThread.class);
    private ExecutorService outputExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public TestClientThread() {
        new Thread(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            LOG.trace("Starting Socket");
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            OutputThread spamming = new OutputThread(s, new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true), new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())));
            exec.execute(spamming);

            spamming.getOut().println("HO HO Ho HO HO");

            InputThread getSpamAnswer = new InputThread(s, new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())));
            outputExec.execute(getSpamAnswer);

        } catch (IOException | JAXBException | XMLStreamException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class TestServerThread implements Runnable {
    private Server king = mock(Server.class);

    public TestServerThread() {
        new Thread(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            king.main(null);
        } catch (IOException | JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            Assert.assertFalse(false);
        }
    }
}
```

First of all there are lot of LOG.trace on the server, but I do not any of it in console, and when I debug I receive an exception that my client could not to connect (I think it did not have time for this). How should I synchronized this?

**P.S. Server is multithread, and support many clients. Now i want only to test it from the source.**

Answer (score 0):

Is your firewall open allowing incoming connections on that port?

Also, you're not really replicating a client-server architecture because there is only one socket that is being shared by all of the 'client' threads. This may be the source of your errors (multiple threads accessing the same object- in this case a stream).

Please see this documentation from Oracle on how to properly setup a client/server demo using separate processes and sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html This will allow you to simulate what would actually happen, and comes with great explanations of the code.

Comment: Yeah i have seen this already. My Server supports not only one client. I think problems is in test. Server do not startup in time. Is there any tools in java Unit testing to test multithreading.

Comment: At the beginning of your code you start a server thread and then several client threads *in the same process*. This does not mirror how client/server architectures normally work, and will not be a good basis to test on. They should be separate programs. Additionally, if you're worried that the ServerSocket isn't ready in time, then I suggest you create the socket at the very beginning of either `run()` or `main()` so that it is listening right away. If that's still not fast enough, you could call `sleep()` for a second before creating the clients.

Comment: and the bottom of the documentation I provided demonstrates how to get a server to accept multiple client connections at once- it does have the information you need.